# Strapi Admin Portal Stuck Loading

Tags: docker

I'm new to Strapi and out of the blue I ran into this issue where whenever I try to access the Strapi Admin page, upon logging in, I get a time limit exceeded of 1000ms and a constant loading screen with a 404 error to the database. Prior to attempting to access the admin page however, the database works fine on my project, after trying to access the admin page it seems to break though. Any clue how to fix this. I'm on a Mac M1 Pro, strapi was working fine up until I made one minor edit to the backend. However, on my Lenovo Strapi admin works completely fine, so I believe this is something to do with docker. [Frontend console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gug84.png)
[Docker logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6gs0.png)